# Как проверить, что подстрока встречается более одного раза?

Tags: java, строки

Есть переменная `String` с двумя вариантами значений:

```
String string= "RUB 1234";
```

либо

```
String string= "RUB 1234 RUB 4567";
```

Необходимо условие, проверяющее есть ли в этой переменной второе **RUB**.

- Если только одно RUB, то...
- Иначе...

Мне нужно само условие. Возможно ли это реализовать?

Comment: Какой должен быть результат для первого и второго вариантов?

Comment: Если только одно RUB, то... Иначе...    Мне нужно само условие

Comment: Можно считать кол-во повторений слова с помощью regex и потом уже проверять по кол-ву..

Comment: Можно пример кода?

Comment: @Артем Ильинский А как ищется первое RUB?

Comment: Да никак пока, в этом-то все и дело. Я не знаю как найти именно ДВА одинаковых слова. Как найти первое - например if(string.contains("RUB");

Comment: Перенес информацию из коммента в вопрос и поправил заголовок. Проверьте все ли я правильно понял.

Comment: Есть еще замечательные методы: `startsWith`, `endsWith`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

С помощью регулярного выражения можно проверить, встречается ли RUB более одного раза. Например:

```
if(string.matches(".*RUB.*RUB.*")) {
   //есть два RUB 
} else {
   //один или ноль RUB
}
```

Можно и без регулярок, сверяя первый и последний индекс:

```
if(input.indexOf("RUB")==input.lastIndexOf("RUB")) {
    //не более одного RUB
} else {
    //более одного RUB
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если задача точно такая и не будет расширяться, то достаточно выполнить дважды подходящий вариант [indexOf](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/string_indexof_string_index.htm)

```
 public int indexOf(String str, int fromIndex)
```

с нулевой позиции и после найденной в первый раз